# Keycloak required action check in authentiation flow

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

Is it possible to **trigger** the executions of all **required actions** for a user **in an authentication execution** (Without finished flow)?

I'm writing a custom login where a user can **login as another user** under specific circumstances. At first the user will be authenticated with the Username Password execution. After this step, the user may choose multiple tenant user via a custom implemented Authenticator. This tenant user is simply set to the context. **- works fine**

But if I need required actions on the original user, only the required actions of the tenant user will checked after the authentication flow. I want to do that **check in the middle of my authentication flow with the required actions of my original user**. (e.g. I want the user to enter the password of update password required action or confirm the terms and conditions action)

Is there e.g. any Service for triggering the check of required Actions just like after the authentication flow?

I tried  AuthenticationManager.actionRequired(...), but apparently isn't the correct way to use in an authentication execution step.

Comment: HEY! I am having experience the exact same problem in my spring project, if anyone had found any solution, please share )) really stuck